# How do I use pod resources like an image on the interface builder in an UIImageView?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, bundle

What I want to do is use image assets from a pod on the Xcode Interface Builder. For example, after installing the pod a user can populate a UIImageView with an image in the pod. To save on space I've stored all the images in `.xcassets`.

I tried altering my podspec, it works fine but doesn't copy assets into the main bundle. I looked into altering the build phases but I haven't found anything on how to add the bundles from the pod to the main bundle. I can access the images through code just fine and display them.

My XCode errors are:

```
framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
Could not load the "Image_In_Pod_Bundle" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Company.ProjectName"`
```

It must be possible to do this because I can see the images on the UIImageView and add them, but when I compile on the emulator/device it won't load the image because it's not in the main bundle still. I haven't found a way to point this at the pod bundles yet but I think I need to either copy the resources into the main bundle or point the UIImageView at the pod bundle.

How do I add pod bundles to the main bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just isn't possible. The way pods work is by being separate bundles so I would need to include the asset in the main bundle to use it on a Storyboard